# Insert or update user data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedure

I inherited an application that uses some stored procedures. Here is a sample of one of the stored procedures used to insert or modify user data.

would like to get the group's opinion on the code. The SQL Server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64).

```
USE [MyDataBase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertOrModifyUserData]    Script Date: 2/2/2016 8:39:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrModifyUserData]
@userName NVARCHAR(200),
@isSuperAdmin BIT = NULL,
@modifiedBy NVARCHAR(200),
@modifiedDate DATETIME = NULL,
@isActive BIT = NULL
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    SET XACT_ABORT ON; 
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION


            IF (@modifiedDate IS NULL OR @modifiedDate ='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
                SET @modifiedDate = GETDATE()
            IF (@isActive IS NULL)
                SET @isActive = 1


            IF ((@userName IS NOT NULL OR @userName <>'') AND (@isSuperAdmin IS NOT NULL OR @isSuperAdmin<>'') AND (@modifiedBy IS NOT NULL OR @modifiedBy <>''))
            BEGIN 
                IF EXISTS(SELECT UserName FROM [dbo].[UserAccess] WHERE UserName = @userName)
                    UPDATE  [dbo].[UserAccess]  
                        SET IsSuperAdmin    = @isSuperAdmin,
                            ModifiedBy      = @modifiedBy,
                            ModifiedDate    =   @modifiedDate,
                            IsActive        = @isActive 
                    WHERE   UserName = @userName    
                ELSE
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserAccess] (UserName, IsSuperAdmin, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate,IsActive)
                    VALUES(@userName, @isSuperAdmin, GETDATE(), @modifiedBy, @modifiedDate, @isActive)  

            END 
        ELSE
            RAISERROR('Required parameters are not provided or Required parameters are passed as NULL',13,1)
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        select null
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();
            RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

END
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Dead code

In this:

> ```
>     COMMIT TRANSACTION
>     select null
> END TRY
> ```

This line of code: `select null` does nothing useful (read: nothing at all) and should be deleted. I have no idea why it is there to begin with, but querying for `NULL` with no criteria will always be null.

---

#### Errors not useful

You could improve this error reporting:

> ```
>     ELSE
>         RAISERROR('Required parameters are not provided or Required parameters are passed as NULL',13,1)
> ```

TLDR: Don't filter error logs, just store stuff. Developers can filter them easily if they need to.

Why? As it is, this is raising an error with no information on "why" the error was raised. At the very least return the input parameters so the user/dev can decipher what is wrong. This is especially relevant if you are logging those errors somewhere.

You would want to include as much relevant information as possible in your errors, especially if there are multiple instances and databases involved. There are few things which hinder improvement and bug fixes more than half-arsed error logs. Log everything and let the developers sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

#### Useless error handling.

Catching and re-raising the error isn't doing anything useful. And you actually are losing potentially valuable information about the line the error occurred.

#### Race conditions.

Unless you are running this at serializable isolation level (the default is read committed) there is nothing preventing two concurrent executions of this stored procedure with the same `@userName` both performing the check for existence at the same time - concluding it is not there and proceeding to insert a row, causing duplicates.

#### Bizarre checks

What is the purpose of `(@userName IS NOT NULL OR @userName <>'')`? There is no possible value that can evaluate to `true` for the second condition that is not already `true` for the first condition. If the purpose was "not null and not empty string" you would need  `(@userName IS NOT NULL AND @userName <>'')` - though that can be simplified to just `(@userName <> '')` in the context you are using it as that won't evaluate to `true` anyway if @userName is null (it would evaluate to `unknown`).

This check is particularly bizarre for `@isSuperAdmin<>''` as the datatype for this is `bit` not string. Due to the wonders of implicit casts this is actually evaluated as `@isSuperAdmin<>0` but is a no-op anyway for the reason discussed earlier.

#### Non conventional custom severity level.

```
 RAISERROR('Required parameters ...',13,1)
```

Why 13? This generally represents deadlock. [Use 16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1122945/73226).

#### Rewrite.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrModifyUserData] @userName     NVARCHAR(200),
                                                @isSuperAdmin BIT = NULL,
                                                @modifiedBy   NVARCHAR(200),
                                                @modifiedDate DATETIME = NULL,
                                                @isActive     BIT = NULL
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      /*Checks for null and empty string. Using IIF as negating unknown won't work as desired*/
      IF IIF(@userName <> ''
             AND @modifiedBy <> ''
             AND @isSuperAdmin IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) = 0
        BEGIN
            /*TODO: Consider making more informative*/
            RAISERROR('Missing values for one or more required parameters.',16,1);  
            RETURN;
        END

      IF ( @modifiedDate IS NULL
            OR @modifiedDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' )
        SET @modifiedDate = GETDATE();

        /*Using Merge to do all in one statement so no need for explicit transactions.
          HOLDLOCK still needed for race conditions though
        */    
        MERGE  [dbo].[UserAccess]  WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS UA
        USING    (VALUES (@userName, @isSuperAdmin, @modifiedBy, @modifiedDate, ISNULL(@isActive,1))) 
                 AS Source(UserName, IsSuperAdmin,  ModifiedBy,  ModifiedDate,  IsActive)
        ON UA.UserName = Source.UserName
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET UserName = Source.UserName,
                     IsSuperAdmin = Source.IsSuperAdmin,
                     ModifiedBy = Source.ModifiedBy,
                     ModifiedDate = Source.ModifiedDate,
                     IsActive = Source.IsActive
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (UserName, IsSuperAdmin, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate,IsActive)
          VALUES (UserName, IsSuperAdmin, GETDATE(), ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate,IsActive); 

  END
```

Comment: Is RAISERROR really suitable? it wont stop the following lines being executed.

Comment: @VincentZHANG - that's why it is followed by `RETURN`